# PHP Send Mail without using SMTP on local WAMP server

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm working on PHP send mail. Here I have using send mail and I have done all local setup Sendmail path but still not getting any mail. what might be the problem here. I don't want to use SMTP(). Below is my sample code. Can you suggest me 1) With SMTP 2) Without SMTP which one is the better choice?

```
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
Mail to:   <input type="text" name="to"><br>
Subject:   <input type="text" name="subject"><br>
Message:   <input type="text" name="message"><br>

<input type="submit" value="SEND">
</form>


<?php
  $to=$_POST["to"];
  $subject=$_POST["subject"];
  $message=$_POST["message"];

  $mail = mail ($to, $subject, $message );
       if($mail == false){
         echo 'Mailer Error ';
       }else{
       echo 'Message has been sent without using SMTP.';
      }
   ?>
```

Comment: So, what have you tried to debug the problem? There might be tons of causes like Sendmail not beeing configured to use a SMTP relay, the relay rejecting your mail, your mail getting to the spam folder,....

Comment: You say you don't want to use SMTP... but the `mail()` function calls your installed sendmail binary (assuming you have one), which opens a synchronous SMTP connection to localhost. Go SMTP; it's both safer and faster, and use PHPMailer to do that, since you tagged your question with it

Comment: I have downloaded the sendmail and setup.

Comment: @Synchro I'm new to PHP can suggest me without SMTP or with SMTP which one is a better choice to use.

Comment: Go with SMTP - as I said, it's both faster and safer, but you'll need to use a library like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to do it - there are plenty of code examples provided to help you do that.